# WSO2 Is 5.0 SP1 : how to send passive calls to WSO2 server for keeping the IDP session active

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Is 5.0 SP1. We want to send passive calls to WSO2 Is from the SP so as to keep the IDP session alive.
I came across [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/02/12/sp-idp-session-time-out-with-saml2-sso/) link

Rule 3 says that we can use SAML2 SSO Passive requests for achieving this but its a browser redirect. Is there any webservice API exposed by WSO2 IS for achieving the same without browser redirects.

Thanks in advance,
Cijoy

Answer (score 0):

Passive SAML2 Auth request,   is same as the normal SAML2 Auth request except on different.  Passive request contains an attribute in the `AuthRequest` called `IsPassive` which must be set to `true`.

Please check the SAML2 [spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) line 2047

Comment: Thanks Asela for your input. How do we achieve it except a browser redirect? i.e send a passive auth request via any webservice call. I want to avoid any browser redirections to keep IDP session alive.

Comment: Sorry.  WSO2IS does not support for web service API to update the session.  Therefore,  only way is to achieve it via browser redirection.  If it is not possible;  We can configure WSO2IS SSO session in to larger value (1-2 weeks)  Then we may not worry about session time out

Comment: Configuring WSO2IS SSO for higher session timeout would mean that the SP would not log out till WSO2 IS session timesout. This would mean a security risk if the application is exposed on internet assuming the user doesn't log out from SP(session will be valid in WSO2 IS). Hence I was thinking of making a Passive Auth Request so that WSO2 session is alive.